# What does dispatching mean

Tags: meaning

I'm waiting to receive an package. The tracking information says 'dispatching'

No one can explain that to me. What does it mean?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure a [simple definition](http://thefreedictionary.com/dispatching) doesn't explain it well enough?

Comment: This is culture-specific business-lingo. In the USA, one might see in the status column of an online tracking page values such as  "in transit" or "at the sorting depot" or "out for delivery".   I could not tell you which of them corresponds to "dispatching".  The name of a department within an organization can end with "-ing".  "He works in shipping" would mean that he works in the Shipping Department.  My `guess` is that the package is still in the warehouse waiting to be put on the truck.

Answer (score 1):

It means they're in the process of sending it. Unfortunately, Tim Romano suggests, it's rather vague regarding what comes within that process. I wouldn't include "in transit" or "out for delivery" -- they're definitely "dispatched". About the most you can infer is that the person responsible for receiving your order has handed it over to the person sending (but not delivering) the goods, but who knows where that boundary is in the organisation?

Answer (score 1):

Dispatching implies that the delivery method is being currently chosen based on cost or speed. Once the best method is chosen, then your package is "in transit". Whether the shipper is using the word accurately is another question. The package may just be sitting on a shelf.